# Is MFC supported in the Community Version of Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

I am migrating some programs from an ancient version of Visual Studio to Visual Studio Community Version 2013.  A few of my projects use MFC.  I am unable to convert these; the immediate problem being the lack of include files such as...

```
#include <afxwin.h>         // MFC core and standard components
#include <afxext.h>         // MFC extensions
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#include <afxdtctl.h>       // MFC support for Internet Explorer 4 Common Controls
```

I understand that MFC is not supported in the Express version of VS but I am running the Community version.

Is MFC supported in the Community Version of VS and if so where do I get these include files?

Comment: Visual Studio Community 2013 includes MFC ([reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/11/12/visual-studio-2015-preview-visual-studio-community-2013-visual-studio-2013-update-4-and-more.aspx)). You may have to manually add the MFC include directories to the include search path.

Comment: Turns out I must have NOT elected to include the MFC stuff when I installed VS.  Ran the installer again and selected MFC; things now ok.  Oldshiemers I guess.